# Why operator precedence and associativity for increment and decrement in java not working properly?

Tags: java

Operator precedence of ++ and -- is higher than + and has associativity right to left. So I think output of x should be (++i+4 then 5+4) 9 and output of y should be (i+++5 then 5+5) 10. For both it print 11 as output.

```
class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        int x = ++i + --i;
        int y = i++ + i--;
        System.out.println("x="+x);
        System.out.println("y="+y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regardless of operator precedence, expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Okay. How I should demonstrate associativity of ++ and -- is right to left.

Comment: @krishna they are unary operators; they don't have left or right associativity.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "has associativity right to left" in your question?  I can't tell what this would mean for `++` and `--`.  In this example, you get the results that you do because the addends are evaluated left to right - that is, `++i` is evaluated _before_ `--i` on the `x` line, and `i++` is evaluated _before_ `i--` on the `y` line.

Comment: Note that `++i + i--` would be 12, and `i++ + --i` would be 10.

Comment: And `i+++++i` will result in a compilation error, while [`int i = 4; System.out.println(i++ + ++i);` will print `10`](https://ideone.com/EiSor5).

Comment: The fundamental issue is that the statement _"Operator precedence of ++ and -- is higher ..."_ ignores the fact that there are TWO `++` and TWO `--` operators with very different semantics.  In addition, the postfix versions have higher precedence than the unary versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's translate this:

```
int i = 5;
int x = ++i + --i;
int y = i++ + i--;
System.out.println("x=" + x);
System.out.println("y=" + y);
```

Into (step by step):

```
int i = 5;
int x = ++i + --i;
//       ^
//   (i = i + 1) + --i
//   (i = 5 + 1) + --i  
//   (i = 6)     + --i
//                   ^
//        6      + (i = i - 1)
//        6      + (i = 6 - 1)
//        6      + (i = 5)
//        6      + 5
// x = 11
int y = i++ + i--;
//       ^
//    (i = 5) + i--
//         5  + i--
//     i = i + 1 // post evaluation, after i was evaluated to 5, now i increments its value and it is 6
//         5 + (i = 6)
//         5 + 6
// y = 11
//     i = i - 1 // post evaluation, after i was evaluated to 6, now i decrements its value and it is 5
System.out.println("x=" + x); // x=11
System.out.println("y=" + y); // y=11
```

Comment: Accepted...! :)

Answer (score 2):

Associativity dictates how operators with the [same precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) are parsed.

For example, the Unary Minus (`- ...`) and Unary Bitwise NOT (`~ ...`) operators have the same precedence and have `right-to-left` associativity. Therefore:

```
int i = ~-1; // == 0
int j = -~1; // == 2
```

Comment: `java` != `javascript`

Comment: Yup :-). Corrected to Java version of answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Section 15.7 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) is clear on this:

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.
>
> *It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.*

Whenever assignment operators and other binary operators are mixed in with increment or decrement operators, evaluating the expression is *not* intuitive, and one should never write such confusing code.

Even if the increment and decrement unary operators are right-to-left associative, the values of an expression are evaluated left-to-right.

```
int x = ++i + --i;
```

Here, `++i` increments `i` to `6` and returns `6`, then `--i` decrements `i` to `5` and returns `5`, and the sum of 6 and 5 is 11.

```
int y = i++ + i--;
```

Here, `i++` returns `5` and increments `i` to `6`, then `i--` returns `6` and decrements `i` to `5`, and the sum of 5 and 6 is 11.

With these expressions, the right-to-left associativity does not figure into the order of operations, because associativity only controls which operations are executed first among operators of the *same* precedence.  You have a `+` operator of lower precedence between them, so the associativity doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this quite old question just for clarification regarding the associativity as it follows:

```
int x = 1;
int z = -++x; // z will end up being -2
```

This happens due to the "Right to Left" associativity of Unary Operators. Also, if the precedence is the same, the result will rely on their associativity.
By the book, if two operators have the same precedence indeed they will have the same kind of associativity.